# contour plot with non linear x scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on two plots: a contour plot on the top and an x-y plot on the bottom [image: contour plot]

The contour plot is done via the following line

```
plt.imshow(df, extent = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
```

while the x, y plot is

```
 xyplot = df.mean()
 plt.plot(x, xyplot)
```

And should be vertically aligned to the contour plot on the top, but the x-y plot has a non-linear x scale. The following picture show the x axis as a function of its index [image]

As I can not provide an array to the "extent" variable of the "imshow" method, I can't provide the some x scale at the contour plot. How can I make the some non-linear scale on the contour plot so that the two plots will result aligned on the vertical axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` to interpolate the image on a regular grid. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
x2 = x ** 2
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
X2, Y2 = np.meshgrid(x2, y)
Z = np.sin(10 * (X**2 + Y**2))
Z2 = np.sin(10 * (X2**2 + Y2**2))

from scipy import interpolate

i2d = interpolate.interp2d(x2, y, Z2)
Zi = i2d(x, y)

fig, axes = pl.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 4))
extent = [0, 1, 0, 1]
axes[0].imshow(Z, extent=extent)
axes[1].imshow(Z2, extent=extent)
axes[2].imshow(Zi, extent=extent)
```

the output:

[image]

left: array calculated on regular grid.
center: array calculated on no regular grid.
right: interpolate result of the center array on regular grid.